# How to access Emacs LISP info manual on MSYS2 version of Emacs

Tags: info

I have been using MSYS2 to run Emacs. I would like to read the info documentation on E-LISP on my computer but the root node doesn't have any Emacs section. The menu command says there is `[No match]` for `Emacs`.

I haven't found a package on Emacs for the info files, nor has pacman been fruitful. Is there a package I'm forgetting? Do I simply need to accept that I have to read online documentation?

I have `msys/info 6.6-1 (base) [installed]`. I have `GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-06-03`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the elisp reference manual from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/info/elisp.info.gz - or at least you would be able to if the GNU web site were up.<sup>1</sup>

Then look at the variable `Info-directory-list`.  It shows the directories where Emacs is looking for Info files.  Put the file into one of those directories, and it should show up.

(If you already have an `*info*` buffer open, you need to kill it and open it again for Emacs to notice the new manual.)

This is a very generic answer - I'm sure there's a way to get MSYS2 to install the manual, but I don't know it.

---

<sup>1</sup> According to https://quitter.im/fsfstatus:

> Most of the FSF sites are now going down for a migration to a new colocation facility. We hope to be back in a few hours. Thanks for your patience! : )
>   4:26 pm - 1 July 2019

Comment: I see that one of the values is `"C:\\msys64\\usr\\share\\info"`. I added `elisp.info.gz` and `emacs.info.gz`. I also tried the .info versions of the files. After restarting Emacs from the MSYS2 terminal info still doesn't display the `Emacs` or a `*lisp` menu. Any idea what I did wrong or how a configuration value could show the downloaded files?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid. One thing you can do is starting Info with a prefix command: `C-u C-h i`. That lets you choose the info file you want to view.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that MSYS overrides the `INFOPATH` environment variable, and doesn't properly translate trailing colons in its value (see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2019-05/msg00000.html and followups).

Add this to your init file to work around it:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'info
  (info-initialize) ; Consult INFOPATH.
  ;; Always add the default value, regardless of what INFOPATH says.
  (dolist (info-dir (Info-default-dirs))
    (add-to-list 'Info-directory-list info-dir)))
```

Comment: That looked so promising, but it doesn't work. I put the code into my .emacs file with all the other code, ran `C-x C-e` and that didn't nor did a restart reveal any different results in the root info page.

Comment: I'm not getting any help finding `info-dir` using `C-h C-v`. Are lists not discoverable as variables?

Comment: I think you meant to capitalize it and give a different variable: `Info-directory-list`.

Comment: @haleonj hmm, works for me (and yes, I tested from MSYS2). `info-dir` is a local variable of the `dolist` (so you won't find any docs for it), `Info-directory-list` is passed to `add-to-list` within the loop. "any different results in the root info page" - did you try scrolling down a bit? The Emacs mauals don't get put at the top. Or just try `C-h r` to jump to Emacs' manual directly.

Comment: `C-h r` works! I found a link to `Emacs Lisp`, and that works too! I think it's strange that neither are menu items in the root menu, but I'll take the win.

Comment: @haleonj They both show up in the root menu for me. If you have already created the root menu before evaluating the lisp in my answer, then you have to kill the `*info*` buffer first though (in order to recreate the root menu with the corrected `Info-directory-list`).

Comment: Do I have to reboot the computer for the changes to take effect? Restarting Emacs didn't work. I see the `Emacs` menu in the root menu *of my Linux box* so I have a known working reference.

Comment: @haleonj no, reboots should not be needed (and I wouldn't expect it to have any effect). Just killing `*info*` is enough to make it work here...

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and as you expected it changed nothing. Now that I know about `C-h r` I this problem is a simple annoyance. If I ever find a way to fix the root directory I'll be sure to add it to this thread, but for now this problem is low priority for me because you both mostly solved the problem.